# Curator:InterProcessMutex Lock.release() didn't delete lock path

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

`Lock.release()` does not delete the lock path? is this a bug?
Do I need to delete the path by myself?

```
 RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryOneTime(1000);
        CuratorFramework client = 
             CuratorFrameworkFactory
               .builder()
               .connectString(zkAddress)
               .sessionTimeoutMs(ZKConstant.ZK_SESSION_TIMEOUT)
               .connectionTimeoutMs(ZKConstant.ZK_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
               .retryPolicy(retryPolicy)
               .build();
        client.start();
        InterProcessMutex lock = new InterProcessMutex(client, "/test_lock");
        if (lock.acquire(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {                 
          LOGGER.debug(curatorUtil.exists(lockPath) == null);
        }

        if (lock != null){
            lock.release();  // After I call this method,
                             // the "/test_lock" node still exists.  Why?
        }
        LOGGER.debug(curatorUtil.exists(lockPath) == null);
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a general problem in ZooKeeper. It's why I added Container Nodes in ZooKeeper 3.5. If you use Curator 3.0 and ZooKeeper 3.5.x the parent nodes will auto-delete. In older versions, you need to use Curator's Reaper and ChidReaper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes！The parent node is not automatically deleted.Because the node actually created is like this

```
/test_lock/"+"_c_"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"-"
```

look

```
CreateBuilderImpl#adjustPath
```

after

```
lock.release()
```

the child node will be deleted.